# Why aren't my images displayed on the homepage

Tags: craft3, templating, entries, matrix, block-types

1. Our homepage.twig is a section
2. Our Matrix is called "angebote" (it's german don't ask :D)
3. We created two entries for our matrix
4. This is our Code inside the homepage.twig file for including the matrix on our page:

[image: Code sample]

Our issue is as follows: the
headline of the matrix will show up correctly but the matrix image won't be displayed. We tried everything the internet has to offer but can't solve the problem. It seems like the issue isnt in the code itself because the image icon is shown, but the image source cant be found.

[image: homepage]

One more notice to give: We have to use an older craft version for our website, in fact :

### **Craft CMS 3.5.13.2**

Additionally here are a few more screenshots of our Craft Configuration:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

We hope you can help or give us some advice

thank you!

Comment: If you view the source of the page, what is the url of the images that won't load?

Comment: you where right. We had to set the base url into @web/assets/images and the file path to @webroot/assets/images
thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @Lina Care to add that as an official answer in case it ends up helping someone in the future?